# What's the relevance of onSaveInstanceState for fragments if it's not always called when the fragment is torn down?

Tags: android, android-fragments

As the doc says:

> There are many situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down
>   (such as when placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its
>   state will not be saved until its owning activity actually needs to
>   save its state.

What's the point? Say you have member variables you want to save when a fragment is destroyed :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong("userId", mUserId);
    outState.putString("username", mUsername);
}
```

When onSaveInstanceState eventually gets called (when the host activity is destroyed for example), those variables don't exist anymore, so you get a null pointer exception.

What's the solution to this?  Thanks!

Comment: A fragment is not "torn down" when it is put on the back stack, mostly because fragments are not put on the back stack. A `FragmentTransaction` can be added to the back stack via `addToBackStack()`. Please edit your question to be **complete and precise** about the scenario that concerns you.

Comment: I understand, but still the doc talks about the fragment, not the FragmentTransaction. :)